# Javascript hide/show elements does not work properly

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, forms, checkbox

I have added this checkbox to my form:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <input type="checkbox" name="prd_presell" id="product_presell" 
      onclick="presellTXT()" value="TRUE" @if(!empty($product)) @if($product->prd_presell == 'TRUE') checked @endif @endif>
    <label for="presell_product">Presell Product</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

So there is an onClick function named `presellTXT()` which goes like this:

```
function presellTXT() {
        var presell_checkbox = document.getElementById("product_presell"); // get checkbox
        
        var presell_text = document.getElementById("show_presell_text"); // text div
        
        var presell_text_input = document.getElementById("presell_product_text"); // text input
        
        if (presell_checkbox.checked == true){
            presell_text.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            presell_text_input.value = "";
            presell_checkbox.value = "";
            presell_text.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

So when the checkbox is checked, it basically shows the element with an id of `show_presell_text`:

```
<div class="row" id="show_presell_text">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Product Presell Text:</label>
      <input name="prd_presell_text" id="presell_product_text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('prd_presell_text', !empty($product) ? $product->prd_presell_text : '') }}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So when the page loads, it should not be showing the **Product Presell Text** unless the checkbox is checked.

Now if you take a look at [jsfillde](https://jsfiddle.net/apnLxuwe/6/) example, you can see as soon as the page loads, the text input appears however the checkbox is not checked at all!

So how to hide the text input when the page loads and the checkbox is not checked?

**Note:** I don't want to use CSS for this because I need to determine correctly if `prd_presell` is checked on page loads (because of `@if($product->prd_presell == 'TRUE')` which retrieves data from the DB) then it has to show the **Product Presell Text** text input.

---

**UPDATE:**

I tried adding this:

```
#show-presell-text.hidden {
    display: none !important;
}
```

And adding this to the div:

```
<div class="row" id="show_presell_text" class="@if(!empty($product)) @if($product->prd_presell != 'TRUE') hidden @endif @endif">
```

But does not work and hide the element.

Comment: document.getElementById("product_presell").value  ,  it is always true if it is checked or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to hide/show the elements on load then this can be easily done by adding an if statement like so

```
@if (!empty($product))
<div class="row" id="show_presell_text">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Product Presell Text:</label>
      <input name="prd_presell_text" id="presell_product_text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('prd_presell_text', !empty($product) ? $product->prd_presell_text : '') }}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endif
```

This will completely omit the element you want at page load if empty and you can add it via JS code. However, If you want to just hide it using CSS classes you can do this:

```
<div class="row" id="show_presell_text" class="@if (empty($product)) hidden @endif">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Product Presell Text:</label>
      <input name="prd_presell_text" id="presell_product_text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('prd_presell_text', !empty($product) ? $product->prd_presell_text : '') }}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the product is empty the class will not be present and you can use CSS to set the element to `display: none` if the class is absent. Let me know if I can clarify further or if I got something wrong.

Edit: A better alternative for the second code block would be to add a hidden class as suggested below if the product is empty and then use it to hide it via CSS. You can then simply add or remove this class via JS as needed.

```
#show-presell-text.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: In your second code block use a `class` instead of not rendering the `id`

Comment: I tried the `hidden` class with `display:none` but didn't work

Comment: What's your level in CSS, Laravel, JS so I know how to assist best. When using classes to reinforce styling there should be no spaces, like in my example, between the `#show-presell-text` and `.hidden` else it will assume the hidden class belongs to a nested element.

Comment: Please see my UPDATE

Comment: As per your explanation and JSFiddle, shouldn't it add the `hidden` class only IF the product is empty? With the current if condition it is the opposite plus sidenote, you can chain the two conditions of the if statement since they're not mutually exclusive to become `@if (!empty($product) && $product->prd_presell != 'TRUE')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try out something like this.

```
<div class="row" id="show_presell_text" style="display: none">
```

By default set the display as none and based on the condition in function set it as block/ none.

Comment: Please take a look at my **Note** in the question. If I use CSS in this case, the text input does not appear even if the checkbox is checked properly!